# MPI_Scatter slows down the code?

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, mpi

Folks! I wrote a code that computes the scalar product of two huge vectors with MPI.
First, the process with rank 0 creates two random vectors and send it via MPI_Scatter to the rest. After that, they compute their partial sums and send it back to the process with rank 0.
The main problem is that MPI_Scatter takes a huge amount of time to send the data to the other processes and, therefore my program gets slower with additional processes. I measured it with MPI_Wtime() and the MPI_Scatter() function took in some cases 80% of the computation time.
My serial code is faster than any MPI-settings that I have tried.

These are my results on my dualcore with different numbers of processes:

Processes   Time

Serial      0,3275

1           0,3453

2           0,4522

4           3,4755

8           5,8645

10          8,9112

20          24,4612

40          63,2633

Do you know how to avoid such bottlenecks?
Dont mind the MPI_Allgather()... it was part of the homework :)

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
srand(time(NULL));
int size, len, whoAmI, i, j, k;
int N = 10000000;
double start, elapsed_time, end;
double *Vec1, *Vec2;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
start = MPI_Wtime();

MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &whoAmI);

if(N%size != 0){
    printf("choose a number that can be divided through 10000000\n");
    exit(1);
}

int chunk = N/size;

double *buf1 = malloc(chunk * sizeof(double));  // Recv_Buf for MPI_scatter
double *buf2 = malloc(chunk * sizeof(double)); 
double *gatherResult = malloc(size*(sizeof(double)));   //Recv_Buf for MPI_Allgather
double result, FinalResult = 0;

if(whoAmI == 0){

    Vec1 = malloc(N * sizeof(double));
    Vec2 = malloc(N * sizeof(double));
    random_Vector(Vec1, N);
    random_Vector(Vec2, N); 
}   

/* sends the divided array to the other processes */
MPI_Scatter(Vec1, chunk, MPI_DOUBLE, buf1, chunk, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Scatter(Vec2, chunk, MPI_DOUBLE, buf2, chunk, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if(whoAmI == 0){
    end = MPI_Wtime();
    elapsed_time = end - start;
    printf("Time taken %.4f seconds\n", elapsed_time);
}

for(i = 0; i < chunk; i ++){
    result += buf1[i] * buf2[i];
}

printf("The sub result: #%d, %.2f\n",whoAmI, result);

/* Allgather: (sendBuf, number of Elements in SendBuf, Type of Send, Number of Elements Recv, Recv Type, Comm)*/
MPI_Allgather(&result, 1 , MPI_DOUBLE, gatherResult, 1, MPI_DOUBLE , MPI_COMM_WORLD);

for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
    FinalResult += gatherResult[i]; 
}

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
end = MPI_Wtime();
elapsed_time = end - start;

if(whoAmI == 0){
    printf("FinalResult is: %.2f\n", FinalResult);
    printf("Time taken %.4f seconds\n", elapsed_time);
    VecVec_Test(N, Vec1, Vec2, FinalResult);  // Test if the Result is correct
}

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are distributing a very trivial process, so I am not surprised. Why would you expect the serialization, deserialization, and network overhead to be cheaper than multiplying two numbers?

Comment: well I am computing a vector multiplication with 10000000 entries so wouldnt a parallelization makes sense? But the somehow the scatter function slows down the code more than the benefits of a parallize multiplication.

Comment: You don't really expect speedup with 40 MPI processes on a dual-core CPU, do you?!

Comment: It was just a test to show that more processes takes more time because of the scatter function. The data output should all be the same because scatter chops down the array. As you can see, 2 processes are also not faster then 1.

Answer (score 4):

Distributed computation of scalar product makes sense only if the vectors are already stored in a distributed fashion, otherwise pushing each time the content of the big vector over the network (or whatever else IPC machanism is in place) from the root to the other processes will take more time that it would take a single-threaded process to do all the work. Scalar product is a memory-bound problem, which means that current CPU cores are so fast that when data comes from the main memory and not from the CPU cache, it will most likely arrive at a slower rate than the CPU core is able to process.

What you could do in order to demonstrate how MPI helps in that case is to modify the algorithm so that the vectors are scattered first and then the distributed scalar product is computed many times:

```c
MPI_Scatter(Vec1, buf1);
MPI_Scatter(Vec2, buf2);

// Always a good idea to sync the processes before benchmarking
MPI_Barrier();

start = MPI_Wtime();

for (i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
   local_result = dotprod(buf1, buf2);
   MPI_Reduce(&local_result, &result, MPI_SUM);
}

end = MPI_Wtime();

printf("Time per iteration: %f\n", (end - start) / 1000);
```

(pseudocode, not real C++)

You should now see the time per iteration decreasing with the number of MPI processes, but only if adding more MPI processes means more CPU sockets and therefore higher aggregated memory bandwidth. Notice the use of `MPI_Reduce` instead of `MPI_Gather` followed by sum.